# Survey invitation sent to email in profile, not my registered email

Tags: support, email, survey-2019

I just noticed the Survey invitation was sent to the *public* email in my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338904/ring-%C3%98?tab=profile) (a mailbox I rarely check).

The email was sent from `stackoverflow.email`, and based on the content, it does not appear to be a scam.

Shouldn't the invitation be sent to the email address that I used when I registered my Stack Overflow account, i.e. the *private* one I use to log in? (the one set in "email settings")

This one is usually also shown in the user profile, but for me, it is a different email address than the one shown publicly. I didn't receive a copy of the Survey invitation in the private, "email settings" one.

Both email addresses never changed, since the beginning.

I don't have a Jobs account.

Comment: Its mostly historical, you've been around long enough to remember.  The login provider was not associated with SO, they did not want to implement one and OpenID was considered a good solution back then.  Still works that way partially with the option to login through Google, I think.